# translating python 3.4 code into python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.4, translate

I having trouble translating this code into python 2.7, i keep getting an error of 'AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute 'maketrans', I'm wondering if anybody could help? The code is supposed to be a Caesar cipher, encrypting words that I input in another section of the code not shown

```
    #
```

Comment: Do you have
from string import maketrans ?

Comment: I just searched the documentation and in 2.7 it's a method of [`string`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans)

Answer (score 1):

Try [`string.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans) instead of `str.makestrans`.